# Incorrect calculating of surface normal of a triangle in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, opengl, collision-detection

I am trying to calculate the surface normal of a triangle in C++ (and OpenGL) based on the 3 vertices of the triangle. I am getting correct results for a non rotated triangle, however I am getting semi-correct result for a rotated triangle. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The expected result should be returning a vector (1, 0, 0) for triangle 1 (non rotated) and (0, 0, -1) for triangle 2 (rotated 90 degrees on Y axis), however I get (1, 0, 0) for triangle 1 and (-4.15243e-08, 1.82413e-08, -1)

As you can see, the first vector and the Z component of the second normal vector is correct, however the X and Y components of the second vector are largely inaccurate as they should both be zero

My code is a very simple function making use of GLM:

```
void CalcSurfaceNormal(glm::vec3 tri1, glm::vec3 tri2, glm::vec3 tri3)
{
        //tri1 tri2 and tri3 are the triangles 3 vertices
        //Simple algorithm followed from another stack overflow article
        glm::vec3 u = tri2 - tri1;
        glm::vec3 v = tri3 - tri1;
    
        glm::vec3 nrmcross = glm::cross(u, v);
        nrmcross = glm::normalize(nrmcross);
        std::cout << "NormalCrs " << nrmcross.x << " " << nrmcross.y << " " << nrmcross.z << "\n";

}
```

Additional info:
The triangle arguments go unchanged as of right now so I can get it working

The first correct call has these vec3s passed in:
(0.970976, -0.0246142, -0.0621899)
(0.970976, 0.0553858, 0.0178101)'
(0.970976, -0.0246142, 0.117237)

The second call which has the last z component correct has these vec3s passed in:
(1.93781, 0.0246142, 0.0290235)
(2.01781, 0.0553858, 0.0290235)
(2.11724, -0.0246142, 0.0290235)

Comment: `-4.15243e-08` and `1.82413e-08` are nearly zero, calling that largely inaccurate is probably a bit wrong.

Comment: `-4.15243e-08`. That's the floating point errors which are to be expected. See, e.g., [Is floating point math broked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Are the argument vectors' values resulting from earlier calculations, that you printed out, or did you input them manually? Did you try to print out the values of vectors `u` and `v`?

Comment: They are resulting from earlier calculations however I have ensured and stepped over ally my code and made sure that these rotated vertices are correct. The values of U and V when printed out for the broken one are "U COMP: 0.08 0.08 -1.86265e-09
V COMP: 0.179427 0 -7.45058e-09"

I think it is a floating point error in C++ itself rather than my code. Anyone know how I can fix this?

I need this value to be dead accurate as I need a seperating axid to perform seperating axis theorem for collision detection

Comment: What do you mean *largely* inaccurate? -0.00000004 is quite close to 0.

Comment: The angle between the correct vector (0,0,-1) and the result is around 0.5 _seconds_... That's not much of a concern IMO

Comment: Nevermind about the largely inaccurate I just saw a 4 and thought it was off by a lot more

Answer (score 3):

`-4.15243e-08` and `1.82413e-08` are nearly zero, calling that largely inaccurate is probably a bit wrong, especially when you take into account that you talk about a vector with the length of `1`.

> Anyone know how I can fix this?`

You will always have floating-point errors, there is no way around that. `sin`, `tan`, `cos`, `pi`, … are only approximations, so you always have to expect errors. What you can do is to use `glm::dvec3` do use `double` instead of `float`, if you need higher accuracy.

> Would this affect collision detection or seperating axis theorem at all? I din't realize the values are almost zero. Although they are still not completely accurate I can imagine this wouldn't mess up SAT too much?

Those inaccuracies can accumulate over time, depending on how you use it. E.g. if you have 3 axis and rotate them separately over time. The angle between them can change noticeably. So it always depends on how you use the results if it is a problem or not.

Comment: If I used this axis to test collisions with separating axis theorem, would I get a lot of false positives or would I not notice a difference? I figure the floating point error is fine as long as it doesn't mess this up.

Comment: Also doubles don't fix the error I just tried. So this isn;t fixable I am assuming? just have to deal with the inaccuracy?

Comment: @user324093252 generally no it should not be a problem. But it depends on how you continue to use the values. That's e.g. the reason why you have a model matrix to that describes the position and orientation of vertexes - that belong together  -  in the scene, instead of directly translating and rotating the vertexes directly over time.

Comment: @user324093252 `Also doubles don't fix the error I just tried.` you can't fix it, you can just increase the accuracy and minimize the error with that.

Answer (score 1):

Single precision floats provide seven significant digits of accuracy (2^-23 relative error). For a vector of length 1, components like 4.10^-8 cannot be distinguished from 0.